# How to modify the xml on onRequestscript() in SOAP UI

Tags: web-services, soap, groovy, soapui

Here is my code which i wrote in onRequestscript

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
path = "D:\\Service\\something2.xml";
log.info("path = "+ path);
if (mockRequest.method == "POST" )
{
mockRunner.returnFile( mockRequest.httpResponse, new File(path))
return new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockResult(mockRequest)
}
```

But this script changes my XML entirely... I want to modify an existing XML(something.xml)..

i was actually Not able to modify the xml so i thought of changinf the xml instead.But according to my business logic its wrong... So can any one help me to modify the xml
in onRequestscript....

XML like

```
<Something>
    <Data1>
      <value>100</value>
    <Data1>
    <Data2>
      <value>200</value>
    <Data2>
</Something>
```

to a modified like this

```
    <Something>
    <Data1>
      <value>101</value>
    <Data1>
    <Data2>
      <value>201</value>
    <Data2>
</Something>
```

Comment: Can you provide example of XML and how it is being changed?
Also I would assume web-service object doesn't change content of XML?!?!

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand modification. You want to put space/tab on the root node? What is the purpose? Web-services typically doesn't care about spaces and stuff like that.

Comment: Oh... I see you want to change values in the nodes....
Let me look at it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **XmlSlurper** to parse and update values from XML file. Then generate a string from updated XML and set it to the response of your mock service.

I use free SoapUI 3.6.1 but it seems that its output object differs from your example. Revise the code for your needs.

```
// get and parse XML file content
path = "D:\\Service\\something2.xml";
def doc = new XmlSlurper().parse(path)

// update values
doc.Data1.value[0] = 101
doc.Data2.value[0] = 201

// generate and return XML string as service response
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
def result = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind{ mkp.yield doc  }.toString()
mockResponse.setResponseContent(result)
```